# Strapi - cannot drop table because other objects depend on it

Tags: postgresql, strapi

I was removing a Content-Type called `Tags` in Strapi and changing all references from it to another Content-Type called `Attributes` and locally it all seemed to work just fine but when I deployed to dev this happened:

```
[2023-06-20 06:09:29.496] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2023-06-20 06:09:29.498] error: drop table if exists "public"."tags" - cannot drop table tags because other objects depend on it
error: drop table if exists "public"."tags" - cannot drop table tags because other objects depend on it
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

I am using PostgreSQL and running on version 4.9.2 of Strapi
I removed Content-Type `Tags` and changed all references in other Content-Types from Tags to another relation. `Tag`s does not exist anywhere in the codebase anymore and locally it seemed to drop the table just fine while doing all this, but when deploying to the dev env the above message keep showing and it just stops.

When I look in the database I still see these references to tags (foreign keys?):
[image: Foreing key not dropped]

They should have been removed right? Is this a bug? or do I need to do something specific?
Fact is that the server won't start anymore.
Any help is appreciated